# Authentication for an entire controller

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I have a project with controllers that need authentication and controllers that not.

I have implemented the documentation about actions composition [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActionsComposition#Authentication), so I inject my `UserAction` in every controller that needs authentication

```
class UserRequest[A](val user: Option[String], request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

class UserAction @Inject()(val parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends ActionBuilder[UserRequest, AnyContent] with ActionTransformer[Request, UserRequest] {

  def transform[A](request: Request[A]) = Future.successful {
    if(request.queryString.contains("token")){
      val token = request.queryString("token").head
      new UserRequest(Some(token), request)
    } else {
      new UserRequest(None, request)
    }
  }

  def PermissionCheckAction(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = new ActionFilter[UserRequest] {
    def executionContext = ec
    def filter[A](input: UserRequest[A]) = Future.successful {
      if (input.user.isEmpty)
        Some(Results.Unauthorized)
      else
        None
    }
  }
}
```

And hte controller :

```
class ResultsController @Inject()(
                                  adRepo: AdRepository,
                                  userAction : UserAction
                                ) extends InjectedController {
```

How to refactor the injections in a parent controller, and apply the useraction on all actions in the controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply your custom action to every controller endpoint. In your case, apply the custom action to every function in your controller that needs authentication.

A little further down in the docs you find how:

```
def tagItem(itemId: String, tag: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) =
 (userAction andThen ItemAction(itemId) andThen PermissionCheckAction) { request =>
   request.item.addTag(tag)
   Ok("User " + request.username + " tagged " + request.item.id)
}
```

The `request` is now a `UserRequest` and the permissions have been checked.

**Edit**

Since you don't have the `ItemAction`, simply rewrite the line to:

```
(userAction andThen PermissionCheckAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible (and handy) way is extract permission check action to trait:

```
trait AuthFilter {
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext
  val userAction: UserAction
  def UserActionWithPermissionCheck: ActionBuilder[UserRequest, AnyContent] = userAction andThen userAction.PermissionCheckAction
}
```

And then use this filter whenever you need:

```
class ResultsController @Inject()(val userAction : UserAction)(implicit val ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends InjectedController with AuthFilter {

  def tagItemProtected(itemId: String, tag: String) =
    UserActionWithPermissionCheck { request =>
      Ok("UserReq: " + request)
    }

  def tagItem(itemId: String, tag: String) =
    userAction { request =>
      Ok("UserReq: " + request)
    }
}
```